# Processing fft crash

Tags: audio, processing, fft

Weird thing. I keep getting processing or *java* to crash with this code which is based on a sample code from the processing website.

On *pc* it doesn't work at all, on one *mac* it works for 5 seconds until it crushes and on another *mac* it just crust and gives me this:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: RtApiCore::probeDeviceOpen: the device (2) does not support the requested channel count.
Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).`

Do you think it's a problem with the library or with the code?
If it's a problem with the library, could you recommend the best sound library to do something like this?

Thank you :)

```
import processing.sound.*;

FFT fft;
AudioIn in;
int bands = 512;
float[] spectrum = new float[bands];

void setup() {
  size(900, 600);

  background(255);

  // Create an Input stream which is routed into the Amplitude analyzer
  fft = new FFT(this, bands);
  in = new AudioIn(this, 0);

  // start the Audio Input
  in.start();

  // patch the AudioIn
  fft.input(in);
}      

void draw() { 
  background(255);
  int midPointW = width/2;
  int midPointH = height/2;
  float angle = 1;
  fft.analyze(spectrum);
  //float radius = 200;

  for(int i = 0; i < bands; i++){
    // create the actions for placing points on a circle
    float radius = spectrum[i]*height*10;
    //float radius = 10;
    float endX = midPointW+sin(angle) * radius*10;
    float endY = midPointH+cos(angle) * radius*10;
    float startX = midPointW+sin(angle) * radius*5;
    float startY =  midPointH+cos(angle) * radius*5;
  // The result of the FFT is normalized
  // draw the line for frequency band i scaling it up by 5 to get more amplitude.
    line( startX, startY, endX, endY);
    angle = angle + angle;
    println(endX, "" ,endY);
 // if(angle > 360){
 //     angle = 0;
 //   }
  }       
}
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you're asking and what language this is. It has elements of C, C++ and Java. Can you please be more specific about what is your code supposed to do? Is it a file-based analysis? How is `draw()` getting called? Which API are you using for analysis, which for drawing? Some relevant information is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you print the values you use like angle and start x,y you'll notice that:

1. start/end x,y values become `NaN`(not a number - invalid)
2. angle quickly goes to `Infinity` (but not beyond)

One of the main issues is this line:

```
angle = angle + angle;
```

You're exponentially increasing this value which you probably don't want.
Additionally, bare in mind trigonometric functions such as `sin()` and `cos()` use radians not degrees, so values tend to be small. You can constrain the values to 360 degrees or `TWO_PI` radians using the modulo operator(%) or the [constrain()](https://processing.org/reference/constrain_.html) function:

```
angle = (angle + 0.01) % TWO_PI;
```

You were very close though as your `angle > 360` check shows it. Not sure why you've left that commented out.

Here's your code with the tweak and comments

```
import processing.sound.*;

FFT fft;
AudioIn in;
int bands = 512;
float[] spectrum = new float[bands];

void setup() {
  size(900, 600);

  background(255);

  // Create an Input stream which is routed into the Amplitude analyzer
  fft = new FFT(this, bands);
  in = new AudioIn(this, 0);

  // start the Audio Input
  in.start();

  // patch the AudioIn
  fft.input(in);
}      

void draw() { 
  background(255);
  int midPointW = width/2;
  int midPointH = height/2;
  float angle = 1;
  fft.analyze(spectrum);
  //float radius = 200;

  for (int i = 0; i < bands; i++) {
    // create the actions for placing points on a circle
    float radius = spectrum[i] * height * 10;
    //float radius = 10;
    float endX = midPointW + (sin(angle) * radius * 10);
    float endY = midPointH + (cos(angle) * radius * 10);
    float startX = midPointW + (sin(angle) * radius * 5);
    float startY =  midPointH + (cos(angle) * radius * 5);
    // The result of the FFT is normalized
    // draw the line for frequency band i scaling it up by 5 to get more amplitude.
    line( startX, startY, endX, endY);
    //angle = angle + angle;
    angle = (angle + 0.01) % TWO_PI;//linearly increase the angle and constrain it to a 360 degrees (2 * PI)
  }
}

void exit() {
  in.stop();//try to cleanly stop the audio input
  super.exit();
}
```

The sketch ran for more than 5 minutes but when closing the sketch I still encountered JVM crashes on OSX.
I haven't used this sound library much and haven't looked into it's internals, but it might be a bug.

If this still is causing problems, for pragmatic reasons I'd recommend installing a different Processing library for FFT sound analysis via Contribution Manager.
Here are a couple of libraries:

1. [Minim](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/fft_class_fft.html) - provides some nice [linear](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/fft_method_linaverages.html) and [logarithmic](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/fft_method_logaverages.html) averaging functions that can help in visualisations
2. [Beads](http://beadsproject.net/) - feature rich but more Java like syntax. There's also a free book on it: [Sonifying Processing](http://computermusicblog.com/blog/sonifyingprocessing/)

Both libraries provide FFT examples.